# understanding flats in a score

Tags: theory, piano

I am trying to learn to read music for piano. I have a piece of music in the key of `F`. It has a `B♭` on the treble clef and a `B♭` on the bass clef. My question is this: is the `B` just below middle `C` also played as a flat? I am sorry if it seems like a simple question, but I can not find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The *key signature* of F major is *every* B now gets flattened, so Bb is played instead. It was deemed that it would be pointless to mark in all the B positions with a flat sign, so only one in each clef is marked. It is then a given that any other B notes written in that piece will also be played as Bb.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for. does this mean that any flat or sharp in a key is to be treated the same.

Comment: Yes. History lesson: originally, key signatures were written on *all* the possible lines of the stave, so a G major signature with F sharp was written  *two* sharps in the treble clef, one on the top line and the other in the bottom space. But by about 1800, people realized this was rather pointless, and stopped doing it.